# Searching database with AJAX and Laravel's blade view

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, searchbar

I'm trying to implement a search feature for an app I'm developing. I have already populated the database with content. So far I am getting the error of the following whenever i enter text into the text field. It has something to do with URL I'm passing into my AJAX.

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#txtSearch').keyup(function(){


        var text = $('#txtSearch').val();

        var dataString = 'text=' + text;

        $.ajax({

            type: 'GET',
            url: "{{ URL::route('search') }}",
            data: dataString,

            success: function(response){

                alert(response);
            }

        });

    });

});
```

routes:

```
Route::get('/search', [

    'uses' => 'HomeController@getSearch',
    'as' => 'search'

]);
```

Controller:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function getSearch(Request $request){

        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
url: "{{ URL::route('search') }}",
```

to

```
url: '/search',
```

And try again. As the Ajax code you are using in written in a JS file and you cannot use blade syntax in JS file.

Comment: Didn't actually know you cannot use blade with js :/

Comment: The answer works, but when using named routes, this is not correct.

Comment: Derek: you cannot use **{{ }}** in JS. Clear your concepts.

Comment: Since when? I am using it currently in my JS

Comment: @Derek you cannot use {{}} it simply displays an error in my application.

Comment: Again, as early as 5.4, you can.

Comment: Derek: you cannot use blade syntax i.e. {{ }} in JS

Comment: @Derek i'm using 5.4.

Comment: You can use it in 5.4 - considering I am a contributing author to laravel, I think I'd know.

Comment: May be I am wrong, but I am not able to use blade sntax in a separate JS file. Working on laravel from past 1 year.

Comment: Bot of yous I am not able to use {{}} in JS. I'm using Laravel 5.4.

Comment: I see the issue. OP is using "main.js" whereas he/she should be including *some* js in a `*.blade.php` to pass laravel variables to and fro (see Laravel CSRF for example)

Comment: If at any point, OP decides to change the route URL, they will have to go through everywhere it is located to fix the url route.

Comment: Derek, it's fixed with @MayankPandeyz solution. No more comments lol. But thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: It might make sense to drop the URI into a meta tag and then grab it later with jQuery in the .js file when the AJAX runs.  That way you can keep using `route('search')` and also keep your javascript outside of your views.

Comment: @user3158900 that's what I was getting at